# How to correct numpy array of offsets?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following numpy array:

```
0 50 100 150
```

Each integer represents an offset, and I want to change one of the values (e.g. 50 to 60). I can do so by doing:

```
my_array[1] = 60
```

However, I want all of the offsets to update accordingly. (Every integer after 50 gets 10 added to it because I changed 50 by 10). What's the easiest way to implement something like this without over complicating anything?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have

```
delta = 10
index = 1
```

You can do

```
my_array[index:] += delta
```

Or in terms of `offset = 60`:

```
my_array[index:] += (offset - my_array[index])
```

Depending on the situation, you may need something more complex. For example, if you have multiple deltas you want to handle simultaneously:

```
deltas = np.zeros_like(my_array)
deltas[index] = delta
my_array += deltas.cumsum()
```

Or alternatively, operate on the diffs:

```
d = np.r_[my_array[0], np.diff(my_array)]
d[index] += delta
my_array = d.cumsum()
```

Comment: Do you mind showing the full code for this actually being implemented for my array that produces the desired result? I'm a bit confused. The desired result should be: 0 60 110 160 since the difference between my_array[1] and the new offset is 10.

Comment: @3qxs7na6. If you copy and paste the lines I show, you will get the result you expect. I've shown you four ways of doing it.

Comment: I copied and pasted it, and it only changes the one value.

Comment: @3qxs7na6. `my_array[index:] += delta` only changes the one value? Perhaps the colon did not copy correctly?